# How to use internationalization in spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I want my application to support multiple locales, I have locale specific properties,

### messages_en.properties:

```
login.username=User Name:
```

### messages_fr.properties:

```
login.username=Nom d'utilisateur:
```

### Below is my servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mobistar.eidsar.controller" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:validation.properties"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/WEB-INF/images/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/css/" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames" value="validation, messages" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" >
        <property name="interceptors">
           <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
           </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

### login.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link href="/eidsar/css/headerStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/eidsar/css/pageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>EIDSAR-Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="header-top">
            <a href="/eidsar" title="Logo">
                <img class="logo" src="/eidsar/images/MobistarLogo.jpg" />
            </a>
            <ul class="lang-nav">
                <li><a id="active" href="?lang=en" title="en">EN</a></li>
                <li><a href="?lang=fr" title="fr">FR</a></li>
                <li><a href="?lang=nl" title="nl">NL</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="header-bottom">
            <div style="visibility:hidden" id="header-content">
                <ul class="head-nav"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="errorblock"><spring:message code="login_unsuccessful_msg" text="default text"/>
            ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}</div>
    </c:if>
    <div class="loginBackground">
        <div class="loginFont">Log In</div>
        <form name='form1' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
            method='POST'>
            <label class="fieldStyle"><spring:message code="login.username" text="default text"/></label> 
            <input class="fieldBox" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 15px;" type='text'
                name='j_username' /> <br>
            <br> <label class="fieldStyle"><spring:message code="login.password" text="default text"/></label> <input
                class="fieldBox" style="margin-left: 25px;" type='password'
                name='j_password' /> <br> <input class="loginSubmit"
                type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I navigate from EN to FR, I am not getting the UserName in FR,

Can anybody help me, what am I doing wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi thej where  the  files are placed(messages_fr.properties,messages_en.properties) in project structure

Comment: I have placed under /eidsar/src/main/resources/messages_en.properties as well as /eidsar/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/messages_en.properties

Comment: attach the source to mailmebaskeran@gmail.com i review code

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your reply! I had to use, <mvc:interceptors>
     <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
         <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
     </bean>
 </mvc:interceptors>